# Odd ng build error

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting an odd error when trying to build an angular 4 app. See below:

```
 Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ptdave/projects/sidr-ts/node_modules/@angular/cli/plugins/named-lazy-chunks-webpack-plugin.js:9:51)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ptdave/projects/sidr-ts/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.js:6:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I'm really at a loss of where to start on troubleshooting this.
I've wiped my node-modules trying to fix this but still have had no luck.

Comment: Hard to tell, can you post a plunkr? Do you have a class called "Class"? Did you forget to `export` a class? Do you extend a class which is not exported or has a private constructor or something?

Answer (score 3):

This happends where you have a class that extends another class that is yet to be initiated. 
Usually because of circular dependencies between the classes

a.js

```
import {c} from c.js
export class a {}
```

b.js

```
import {a} from a.js
export class b { }
```

c.js

```
import {b} from b.js
export class c extends b{}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to get angular/typescript to identify? That error message is the only thing I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the issue. For whatever reason, my package.json did not contain webpack from angular-cli. Starting a fresh node_modules then messes with the entire thing. Thanks for the guesses anyhow.